# English word for rope used to tie a cow

Tags: single-word-requests

I wanted to know if there is an English word to describe the rope used to tie a cow to its place (pole, etc) or a word to describe the process of tying a cow to its place (pole, etc).

I hope I have described it clearly so that you can understand. Please feel free to ask if I wasn't clear enough.

Comment: Are you asking about the rope itself or the knot used ([cow hitch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cow_hitch))?

Comment: Is there such a word in your native language? And is it specific to cows or would it work for goats or horses?

Comment: @Lawrence - I googled about HitchKnot it's not what I was looking for. It is specifically the used to describe the rope used to tie a cow(any cattle animal). Also, the process of doing that has a word as well.

Comment: @Mitch - Yes we have a word for rope and the process of tying also has a word. Its not specific to cows but cattle in general.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The word you are looking for is [**tether**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/tether) it applies to various four-legged animals capable of being [tethered](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/16840/when-were-domesticated-animals-tethered-on-a-pole-with-a-rope).

> **verb**
>
> Tie (an animal) with a rope or chain so as to restrict its movement.
>
> - ‘He still makes traditional cow bands, used by farmers for tethering cattle and other farm jobs, out of Egyptian flax on an old-fashioned rope-making sled and top.’
> - ‘Cows were tethered near the wall, to provide milk, ghee and cow dung for the rituals.’

and

> **noun**
>
> A rope or chain with which an animal is tied to restrict its movement.
>
> - ‘If enacted, the law might eliminate tethers and stalls for other classes of cattle.’

[image: In tethering, animals can be tied to a peg or onto a wire using sliding knot. It is popular in areas of high population and where few animals are kept]

The Australian Veterinary Association provides specific [guidelines for tethering animals](https://www.ava.com.au/node/70991)

> Tethering is defined as the securing of an animal to an anchor point to confine it to a desired area. It is used to prevent animals (e.g. dogs) straying in the owner’s absence or to allow animals (e.g. sheep and goats) to graze unfenced pasture. **Tethering should not be confused with short-term tying up or with hobbling.**
>
> These guidelines have been developed to assist people to tether animals correctly when circumstances make it a necessary method of confining and protecting animals. They specify the requirements for tethering dogs, sheep, goats, *cattle*, donkeys and horses.

The origins of tether are

> Late Middle English: from Old Norse tjóthr, from a Germanic base meaning ‘fasten’.

[Collins Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/tether) also has excellent definitions for [**tether**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/tether).

Nowadays tether has a second meaning too.

> usually as a noun tethering
>
> Use (a smartphone) in order to connect a computer or other device to the Internet.
>
> ‘one prediction is that tethering will cost around $30 per month, probably with some cap on the amount of data transfer allowed’

**Hobbling** as referred to in the AVA guidelines above is when the animals back legs are tied to prevent them from kicking, e.g. when milking a cow or when cows are calving.

The devices are known as [**hobbles**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/hobble), [**kickers**](https://hambydairysupply.com/livestock-supplies/cattle-restraint-cow-kickers-hobbles-and-bul/), [**spancels**](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/spancel) or [**fetters**](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/fetter?s=t)

Hobble, spancel, and fetter can also be used as verbs when they are being applied to the animals.

There is an idiomatic expression "to be ***at the end of your tether***" which derives from the word.

> ***at the end of your rope*** having no strength or patience left:
>
> By six o'clock after a busy day I'm at the end of my tether.

Comment: This is a great answer, and I’ve upvoted. But ... it’s not very cow-specific. :P

Comment: Thanks Lawrence, I gathered that while I was writing it, but then I rationalised that the term applies to most four-legged animals that can be tethered. I'll add some cow-related example sentences. :-D

Answer (score 1):

I think you are referring to a ***[halter:](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/halter)***

> a : a rope or strap for leading or tying an animal

(M-W)

[image]

From www.martinsupply.com

[image]

Weaver leather rope halter.

Comment: Most halters only include the part around the animal's head though, not the rope.

Comment: @Laurel - that p’s part of the halter, please read the definition given in M-W and see https://www.google.it/search?q=cow+halter&rlz=1C9BKJA_enIT753IT753&hl=it&prmd=sivn&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj0gNy9w4zdAhWJMewKHepwBDcQ_AUIEigC&biw=768&bih=909#imgrc=9jWhpesBqgsXmM:

Comment: I learnt a new word today, +1! (Which I’ll no doubt have forgotten again in five minutes.)

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet - is it really that unusual? Not to me, I was born in the countryside, with cows, goats, chickens, dogs and cats...

Comment: @user070221 I grew up in the countryside, but in a gentrified area. The existence of a specific word for this makes perfect sense (agricultural vocabulary is often highly specific), but never even occurred to me before.

Comment: Thanks for that word too, but I was looking for tethering

Comment: I think you've misinterpreted the pictures. In leather goods for controlling work animals , the part around the muzzle, cheeks, and ears is called the 'halter', [the part that goes from the halter to the person is called the 'lead' or 'lead rope'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horse_tack#Halters). I'm not sure if that is the same as what the OP wants though. I'm just supporting @Laurel's point.